# R leaflet shiny app can,t appear in shiny.io

Tags: r

I am currently trying to create a simple website to display my research results. I am using Leaflet to overlay the resulting layers onto a map. However, I am having a problem: Leaflet runs everything fine in RStudio and the layers are displayed correctly. However, when I publish the site to shinyapps.io, the map and layers are displayed incorrectly (as shown below), along with my shiny.io logs. Thanks!

[shiny.io Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TLsR.png)
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whsz9.png)

Below is my code:

app.R

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(mapdata)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(mapview)
source("test ui.R")
source("test server.R")
ccdata <- read.csv("./ShinyCCData.csv")
cctv <- read.csv("./slide.csv")
slope_raster <- raster("./Soil Loss2.tif")
sheet_erosion_raster <- raster("sheet soil.tif")
sheet_rill_erosion_raster <- raster("sheet and rill.tif")
rill_erosion_raster <- raster("rill soil.tif")
sheet_deposition <- raster("sheet deposition.tif")
sheetandrill_deposition <- raster("both deposition.tif")
rill_deposition <- raster("rill deposition.tif")

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)
ccdata <- read.csv("./ShinyCCData.csv")
cctv <- read.csv("./slide.csv")


# 頁數 1 - Introduction ----------------------------------------------
intro_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Introduction",
  
  titlePanel("Nan-Feng Village Soil Erosion"),
  
  img(src = '123.png', height = 400, width = 800),
  br(), br(),
  
  p("WOWWOWWOW"),
  
)

# 頁數2  - Vizualization -------------------------------------------
select_values_1 <- colnames(ccdata)
select_values_1 <- select_values_1[! select_values_1 %in% c('Sex', 'Age.Range')] # remove unwanted columns

sidebar_content_1 <- sidebarPanel(
  selectInput(
    "y_var",
    label = "Y Variable",
    choices = select_values_1,
    selected = "Drug.Cost"
  )
)

main_content_1 <- mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot")
)

second_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Bar Graph",
  titlePanel("5222"),
  p("55555555"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebar_content_1, main_content_1
  )
)

third_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Nan-Feng Village disaster site",
  titlePanel("Nan-Feng Village disaster site"),
  
  leafletOutput("slope")
  
  
)




four_panel <- tabPanel(
  "Rusle",
  titlePanel("Rusle"),
  
  leafletOutput("rusle1"),
  htmlOutput("legend")
  
  
  
  
)
five_panel <- tabPanel(
  "USPED",
  titlePanel("USPED"),
  
  radioButtons("erosion_type", "Select Erosion Type:",
               choices = c("Sheet erosion", "Sheet and Rill erosion", "Rill erosion"),
               selected = "Sheet erosion"),
  leafletOutput("usped_map")
  
)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Soil erosion",
  intro_panel,
  second_panel,
  third_panel,
  four_panel,
  five_panel
  
)
```

Server.R

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
ccdata <- read.csv("./ShinyCCData.csv")
cctv <- read.csv("./slide.csv")
breaks <- c(0, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130, 150)
colors <- colorNumeric(palette = c("green", "yellow", "red"), domain = breaks)


aggdata<-ccdata %>% group_by(Age.Range, Sex) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(),mean)) %>% as.data.frame()

# Create server -------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(data=aggdata, aes_string(x='Age.Range', y=input$y_var ,fill='Sex', shape='Sex', color='Sex')) +
      #geom_point(stat="identity", position='dodge')+
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position='dodge') +
      labs(x="Age Range", y=input$y_var) + 
      scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Under 65","65-69", "70-74", "75-79","80-84","85 and above"))
    
    #+ coord_flip() #horizontal vs vert bars
    
  })
  
  output$slope <- renderLeaflet({
    slope <- leaflet(data=cctv)
    slope <- addTiles(slope)
    slope <- addMarkers(slope, lng=~lng, lat=~lat)
    
  })
  
  output$rusle1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addRasterImage(
        slope_raster,
        colors = colors,
        opacity = 1
      
      ) 
      
  })
  
  output$legend <- renderUI({
    legend_html <- capture.output(help("plot.default", package = "graphics"))
    
   
    legend_html <- gsub("</h2>", "</h2><h3>Soil Erosion Classification</h3>", legend_html)
    color_blocks <- sapply(seq_along(breaks[-length(breaks)]), function(i) {
      sprintf('<div><span class="color" style="background-color:%s"></span>%d - %d</div>',
              colors(i), breaks[i], breaks[i + 1])
    })
    legend_html <- c(legend_html, unlist(color_blocks))
    
    HTML(legend_html)
  })
  
  
  
  output$usped_map <- renderLeaflet({
    erosion_type <- input$erosion_type
    
    

  
    
    if (erosion_type == "Sheet erosion") {
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addRasterImage(
          sheet_deposition,
          colors = colors,
          opacity = 0.7,
          layerId = "sheet_deposition"
        ) %>%
        addRasterImage(
          sheet_erosion_raster,
          colors = colors,
          opacity = 0.7,
          layerId = "sheet_erosion_raster"
        ) 
        
    } else if (erosion_type == "Sheet and Rill erosion") {
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addRasterImage(
          sheetandrill_deposition,
          colors = colors,
          opacity = 0.7,
          layerId = "sheetandrill_deposition"
        ) %>%
        addRasterImage(
          sheet_rill_erosion_raster,
            colors = colors,
            opacity = 0.7,
            layerId = "sheet_rill_erosion_raster"
        ) 
        
    } else if (erosion_type == "Rill erosion") {
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addRasterImage(
          rill_deposition,
          colors = colors,
          opacity = 0.7,
          layerId = "rill_deposition"
        ) %>%
        addRasterImage(
          rill_erosion_raster,
          colors = colors,
          opacity = 0.7,
          layerId = "rill_erosion_raster"
        ) 
   
    }
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
}
```

The current shinyapps.io link.
[text](https://yoyottw.shinyapps.io/Soilwowowow/)

I'm a newcomer to R and I hope to resolve this issue. Thank you!